# ASP.Net MVC 6 authentication and authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I Have developed a simple ASP MVC 5 app with two pages. I have started the project with ASP MVC empty templates. Now I have to implement authorization and authentication for it. In my case have to get all authentication and authorization (UserRoles and IsInRole information) details from another party.

So I Googled and found two possible ways to do my task. But I'm totally beginner for identity and custom membership providers.

- Using ASP.Net Identity
- Using custom Role and Membership provider.

What would be the best way to do this? Can any one suggest a good resource to follow or is there are any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the a little of history -

1. Membership Provider *(introduced with ASP.NET 2.0 in 2005)*
2. Universal Providers
3. Simple Membership
4. **ASP.NET Identity**

If you are implementing a new web application, **ASP.NET Identity** is the way to go.

*ASP.NET Identity is a steep learning curve. Scott Allen has a free [ASP.Net Identity](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals&author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&clip=0&mode=live) course at PluralSight.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to extend the Asp.NET Identity classes that work with the third party. This allows you to use the base classes yet use the third party to get the authorization details.

Here is a link that explains the different parts of the ASP.NET Identity. From there you should be able to decide which classes you need to extend. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: The link points to old ASP.Net Identity. A lot of things got change in ASP.Net Identity 2.